# How to load some js scripts asynchronous by jquery?

Tags: jquery

There is one javascript file http://v2.jiathis.com/code_mini/jia.js, in order for good speed , I want to load it asynchronous, how to do this by jquery ?

Comment: The script isn't that large.  You most likely don't need to load this async as it probably won't make that much of a difference.

Comment: The loading is very slowly for me :(

Comment: Are you hosting it locally? If not, I would try that and see if that improves the results.  I can query the script with a sub second response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.getScript() can help you the things [Getscript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/): 
load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

The script is executed in the global context, so it can refer to other variables and use jQuery functions. Included scripts can have some impact on the current page

```
$.getScript("yourJavascriptUrl", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
   console.log(data); //data returned
   console.log(textStatus); //success
   console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
   console.log('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
$.ajax({
  url: http://v2.jiathis.com/code_mini/jia.js,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

or

getScript();

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://v2.jiathis.com/code_mini/jia.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

> If html is specified, any embedded JavaScript inside the retrieved
>   data is executed before the HTML is returned as a string. Similarly,
>   script will execute the JavaScript that is pulled back from the
>   server, then return nothing.